# Different locking behaviour from jetty to WAS

Tags: jakarta-ee, jdbc, db2, websphere

I am working on a web application with processes running on separate threads using spring's taskexecutor (uses workmanager on WAS and threadpool on jetty).

The app uses spring/hibernate/db2(udb).

The async process creates a record with the status and progress, which can be viewed in a page with the process history.

When running on websphere and attempt to access the list of processes, it seems to be waiting for the process to finish and finally throws a "file in use" sql exception and rollbacks the changes. This does not happen on jetty with same database.

My question is, why am I seeing different locking behaviors from jetty to websphere and how can I fix this. jdbc driver settings are default on both.

Comment: I do not have much info about the dbms setup. To clarify, both jetty and WAS are setup to use the same database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the two containers use different transaction isolation levels. See if this helps for WAS: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas8N1012999. To quote, "This document will discuss how, what, and where transaction isolation levels are set in WebSphere Applications by default and for specific resource references."

Comment: Thanks for the link, that really helped. The problem seems to be two-fold.    
1. WAS defaults to Repeatable read. I set the  webSphereDefaultIsolationLevel DS property and resource_ref extension to READ_COMMITTED. The problem still persisted with slightly different symptoms.     2. Updates to the status records were not being committed. I added propagation=REQUIRES_NEW in @Transactional to the status methods so that logging runs in a separate transaction.    
I'm guessing i didn't experience any probs with jetty because it defaults to read_uncommitted. Will run some more tests to confirm.

Comment: I removed the READ_COMMITTED setting and I'm not getting the file in use problem. Setting the TR propagation resolved the issue. This confirms that jetty defaults to READ_UNCOMMITTED